# What can I do to moderate my talking volume better when interacting with a group of people?

Tags: conversations, groups

When I was in school I was active in Choir and Theater and learned to project my voice well. Topped off by a several years in the Army reinforcing the commanding tone, combined with a lack of awareness on my part leads to my talking in a loud voice unintentionally.

The only technique I have been successful with is reducing the opportunities by intentionally staying out of conversations unless I am directly asked questions. This reduces the occurrence of the problem but does not solve it. Many times I have been asked to bring my volume down, even in meetings. It is not something I am doing consciously though.

I seem to notice it becomes more of a problem when I am trying to assert my position. I am told it makes me seem like I am trying to dominate rather than convince, which is not my conscience intent. As a result my arguments for my position are often less effective than when I do manage to control my volume and tone.

Is there anything I can do to keep from becoming boisterous while talking with others?

Comment: Because, at least in my opinion, this isn't a problem related directly to talking to someone, it could be an issue in general. Almost like "other people find my voice annoying how can I get them to listen to me", a solution to this problem would be to talk quieter, which is not an interpersonal solution, it's a personal one.

Comment: I'm not sure how I feel about this question. I think it's a good one - you got an upvote from me - and it might be on-topic because proper communication is needed for interpersonal skills. On the other hand, the question isn't about how to act in a certain situation, which seems to be what most posts here are about.

Comment: I think that "controlling the volume of your speaking voice" is well within the skillset one needs to master for interpersonal interaction. Speaking too loudly (or softly) affects your ability to communicate with others. As such, learning how to control this would be an interpersonal skills issue. How many films contain characters with this problem? Most recently, the *Pitch Perfect* series made light of a character who spoke too softly for anyone to hear, which affected her ability to interact with her peers.

Comment: [Meta post.](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/176/102)

Comment: @Chad I think that would certainly reduce the scope of the question to something much more manageable.

Comment: @HDE226868 - I have refined the question some.  I really would like to keep it as broad as possible to help make the answers more useful to others, but if the scope is still to broad I am willing to refine it further.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because that's rather an issue related to intrapersonal skills.

Comment: @avazula I'd argue that **intra**personal skills relate to feelings that are internal and while they may influence how you act with others, they only directly affect you. OP here is asking how they can act around others to appear less "dominating" and annoying to those in the area. To me this seems more interpersonal than intrapersonal. They're asking how to change how they act with others, not how they can change themselves for themselves.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, as I am deaf in one ear. I regularly get told not to speak so loudly. The only thing you can really do is purposefully speak at a lower volume than your ears tell you you should.

Something that can help, is to pretend you are wearing headphones. When you are listening to music on headphones you *know* you have to talk more quietly than the sound of your own voice tells you to. If you can visualise yourself wearing headphones whenever you're having a conversation, it may help you to remember to dip your voice.

And getting a hearing test to confirm that this is the problem is probably a good idea.